# Trim An json Array via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

How Can I Trim This Array? I Want to echo First Object of My Array,That is `id`, I Mean 3 Row of `id`

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
 $sql="SELECT `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

    $json = $row[0];
    $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($jason_array as $data){
        $id[] = $data['id'];
        //$answer[] = $data['answer'];
      // $type[] = $data['type'];

        // here code to insert/update values to db column
    }

    echo implode(',',$id)."</br>";
   // echo implode(',',$answer);
  //  echo implode (',',$type);
  }

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And Please Take a Look to Output in This Photo
[image: My Output]

Comment: print_r($id) and putt in question

Comment: Incorrect, it give me ```Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 30 [2] => 31 [3] => 32 [4] => 33 ) Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 30 [2] => 31 [3] => 32 [4] => 33 [5] => 40 [6] => 30 [7] => 31 [8] => 32 [9] => 33 ) Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 30 [2] => 31 [3] => 32 [4] => 33 [5] => 40 [6] => 30 [7] => 31 [8] => 32 [9] => 33 [10] => 100 [11] => 200 [12] => 300 [13] => 400 ) ```

Comment: The [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is wrong way of used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re initialize the $id array. Try this

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
 $sql="SELECT `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

    $json = $row[0];
    $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);
    $id = array();
    foreach ($jason_array as $data){
        $id[] = $data['id'];
        //$answer[] = $data['answer'];
      // $type[] = $data['type'];

        // here code to insert/update values to db column
    }

    echo implode(',',$id)."</br>";
   // echo implode(',',$answer);
  //  echo implode (',',$type);
  }

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what is changed here?

Comment: Yesssssssss, Appriciate It.